# OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) Making Zsh Very Slow

Tags: macos, zsh, homebrew, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I just freshly installed El Capitan on my MacBook Pro. I had trouble earlier with the my terminal being too slow while typing in simple commands. I thought it might have been that I need to format my drive and install 10.11.

After re-installation. It turns out nothing changed. Still my iterm is very heavy. When I tried to further investigate this, it turns out that I don't have this problem when running on a bash shell. I only have this issue with Zsh.

I use homebrew, iterm2, and oh-my-zsh. I hope someone can shed some light on this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior with iTerm and the default bash shell. The entire system seems to stutter at times, honestly, even outside the shell, so I'm not sure if this issue is constrained to just iTerm/shell, but it does manifest there.

Comment: Well! I was thinking that since apple made major changes to OS X; such as, introducing metal for graphics and many other things, then it would be natural to face such issues. I decided I don't want to go through this right now, so I rolled back to Yosemite. I'm disappointed, but let's give them a couple of months. Good luck.

Comment: After taking the answer's advice below, I did: code-select --install, and indeed it seems to have corrected my terminal performance. Hoping that's the end of the story.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install or update Command Line Tool of XCode.

1. Start XCode.
2. Go to XCode/Preferences.
3. Click the "Downloads" tab.
4. Click "Components".
5. Click "Install" on the command line tools line.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will give a try; however, I have already decided to rollback to Yosemite and give El Capitan sometime to mature. 99% of my work depends on the terminal, and that's the one thing I can't compromise. Thank you @kenorb greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did not help me :-( I had it installed already, but reinstalled using cli.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be an issue with oh-my-zsh plugins listed in my .zshrc

Since I had a fresh install and copied my dotfiles immediately to the system some of the plugins i have listed in my .zshrc such as ruby's rvm and pyton's virtual env were not yet installed. This caused zsh to recursively keep looking in my $PATH folders for these tools and cause this annoying delay issue in my terminal

I removed these plugins from .zshrc before installing these command-line tools first. After installing everything I listed the plugins back, and now everything works fine.

Hope this help others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

My zsh using zgen and oh-my-zsh was also running slow after a fresh install of El Capitan.

Narrowing it down, it turned out to be my theme's (S1cK94 minimal) git support that didn't play well with the OS-provided git. After installing the latest git version via Homebrew, zsh is up to speed again.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update Homebrew after upgrading to El Capitan? (see here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md )

Thereafter, (re)-install git:

```
brew install git
```

Then try editing .zshrc by adding:

```
function git_prompt_info() {
  if [[ "$(command git config --get oh-my-zsh.hide-status 2>/dev/null)" != "1" ]]; then
          ref=$(command git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || \
                          ref=$(command git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return 0
                  echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX${ref#refs/heads/}$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX"
                    fi
            }
```

Comment: oh-my-zsh does not like git from apple.  `vi-mode` plugin REALLY does not like Apple's version ...

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue with powerline status-line plug-in and it's problem with querying and displaying the git status. I removed the git display item (**vcs**) from the left powerline prompt setup in the .zshrc file and the lagginess disappeared.

No git status display though, so this is just a temp fix for me.

[edited propmt parameter for powerline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Zbc.png)